# Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers. for Multi organization hyperledger fabric 1.1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to setup hyperledger fabric +  composer setup with multi organizations locally. The steps I followed to setup hyperledger network is below.

> Generate crypto materials and channel

- cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml configtxgen -profile
  OrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
- configtxgen -profile Channel -CreateChannelTx
  ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID ehrchannel
- configtxgen -profile Channel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Hospital1MSPanchors.tx -channelID ehrchannel -asOrg Hospital1MSP
- configtxgen -profile Channel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Hospital2MSPanchors.tx -channelID ehrchannel -asOrg Hospital2MSP

  > Start docker containors for two organisations
  >   Execute Below commands on cli containor
- peer channel create -o orderer.ehr.com:7050 -c ehrchannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/ehr.com/orderers/orderer.ehr.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.ehr.com-cert.pem

> Having all peers join the channel with setting appropriate env veriables
>    - peer channel join -b ehrchannel.block
>   Updating anchor peers for two organisations by setting env variables

- peer channel update -o orderer.ehr.com:7050 -c ehrchannel -f ./channel-artifacts/Hospital1MSPanchors.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/ehr.com/orderers/orderer.ehr.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.ehr.com-cert.pem

After that I have followed [Hyperledger composer document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) to configure composer.
But on step 17 on the doc, I am getting an error

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@ehr-network-hos1 -a marbles-network.bna -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A admin1 -C admin2/admin-pub.pem -A admin2 -C admin2/admin-pub.pem
Starting business network from archive: marbles-network.bna
Business network definition:
        Identifier: marbles-network@0.1.14
        Description: Marble Trading Network

Processing these Network Admins:
        userName: admin1
        userName: admin2

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (marbles-network:0.18.2))
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (marbles-network:0.18.2))
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (marbles-network:0.18.2))
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (marbles-network:0.18.2))

Command failed
```

What are the potential issues? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Did you perform a composer runtime install ? if you did then you likely have got the -n parameter wrong. The error is saying it cannot find a composer runtime on the peer with the right name 'marbles-network'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What versions of Composer and Fabric are you using ?  If you are using Composer v0.18.2 you need to have the GA version of Fabric v1.1.

The releases document for Composer details the compatible versions of Composer and Fabric. https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases

Also you might have a typo in your command `... -A admin1 -C admin2/admin-pub.pem -A admin2 -C admin2/admin-pub.pem` are you specifying the wrong folder for admin1 ?

Comment: There was a typo in the composer network start command and the network name given in the composer runtime install command and the sample project were different. After modifying the above, now network has been started successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Check fabric node logs to find clue:

`docker logs [orderer/peer/...]`